# How do I remove hundreds of automatically added network printers?

Tags: networking, printing, avahi

It is very difficult for me to perform printing, because the printer dialogue is full of hundreds of automatically added printers, so I can't find the one I want to use, see screenshot below.

[image: Image of printer dialogue showing a very long scroll bar]

The printers stem from my work network, where apparently lots of people (including students, I guess) are "sharing" their home printers, which my laptop then picks up automatically. (coincidentally I sometimes disable the avahi-daemon at work, simply because it is using a large amount of CPU).

When I go to `http://localhost:631/printers/`, it says there are 131 printers, and they are all of Make and Model 'Local Raw Printer'. With two exceptions: 1 is a network printer at work that I manually configured. Another is a network printer at my parents', which was also automatically added and which I am on the same network as right now. But the rest are just garbage that I would really like to avoid. Tips on how to do that would be appreciated.

I will not be going back to my work place for a bit of time though, so for now, I would just like these printers (that would be the 129/130 automatically added printers) to be removed. Is there a way to do that? I guess I could do it by clicking through in the cups web interface, but for 129 printers, that is a bit much. So I am looking for a single command or tips on how to achieve it with a script of sorts.

Comment: see /etc/cups/printers.conf. stop cups and then remove the printers from the file.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because I am asking how to remove already installed printers, while that other question is about preventing their installation. Also, it's a question which has a hot mess of outdated answers which don't work. I know this because I've seen it before and tried some of it.

Comment: Understood, retracted :)

Comment: What bugs me is that when I press in the printers administration window GUI refresh button, they do not disappear.  They system should attempt to contact them and remove any network printer that is not responding.  Anybody aware of any bug/feature request regarding this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using this command: `lpstat -a` we can see the installed printers and identify the name of the desired printer to keep, we can use the `grep` command also to filter the results like so: `lpstat -a | grep <probable_name_of_printer>`.

Then this little script can help:

1. Run this command to check that the desired printer is not listed:

   ```
   lpstat -a | cut -d" " -f1 | sed -E '/<NAME_OF_PRINTER>/d' | grep <NAME_OF_PRINTER>
   ```

   - This should return nothing as it does the following:

     - `lpstat -a`: list installed printers
     - `cut -d" " -f1`: return only the names of the printers
     - `sed -E '/<NAME_OF_PRINTER>/d'`: remove the name of the printer to keep from the output of the previous commands
     - `grep <NAME_OF_PRINTER>`: make sure the desired printer is not on the list
2. If the above checks out; then run this command to remove every other printer that you don't need:

   ```
   sudo bash -c 'for i in $(lpstat -a | cut -d" " -f1 | sed -E '/<NAME_OF_PRINTER>/d'); do lpadmin -x "$i"; done'
   ```

Comment: This looks promising. I think there might be an issue though (with the listing command so presumably also the last command). `lpstat -a` results in `<printer_name> not accepting request since <some date> -\n reason unknown` (with `reason unknown` on a new line!). So using your listing command I get a lot of "printers" named `    reason` (there's an indentation).

Comment: Please which part of the steps are you having issues and add any results to your question so I can follow! What does the command `lpstat -a` give you?

Comment: It worked fine, but I added another `sed` command in the "pipe chain": `sed -E /reason/d` to be rid of the extra lines.

Comment: Great work and glad it worked!